# Converting any kind of date format to MM\DD\YYYY

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

I am converting this 2 sets of date to the format `MM\DD\YYYY`

1.`Thu Aug 31 15:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017`

2. `2017-08-09`

When I'm converting the 1st one I use this code.

```
var STD_Date = STD_data[i][4]; //<----This is where the date comes.
var date = convertDate(STD_Date);
var datearray = date.split("/");
var New_STDDate = datearray[1] + '/' + datearray[0] + '/' + datearray[2];
```

This is the function `convertDate()`

```
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

This is how I format the second one.

This is the function

```
  var toMmDdYy = function(input) {
    var ptrn = /(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})/;
    if(!input || !input.match(ptrn)) {
        return null;
    }
    return input.replace(ptrn, '$2/$3/$1');
};
```

This is how I use it.

```
var startdate = form.startdate //<--- comes from HTML Picker (Format "YYYY-MM-DD")
toMmDdYy(startdate)
```

My question is this how can I have a function that will format the date whether it is the 1st or the 2nd one?

```
Convert_TimeStamp_Date(){
  //This is where to code will go to convert
  //to MM\DD\YYYY
}

//Then call it
var startdate = "2017-08-08"
var timestamp = "Thu Aug 31 15:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017"
Convert_TimeStamp_Date(startdate);
Convert_TimeStamp_Date(timestamp);
//both of them the output must be "MM\DD\YYYY"
```

This is the current code but looking forward for a better one. **WORKING**

```
//Time Stamp to MM\DD\YYYY
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  var chopdate = [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
  var datearray = chopdate.split("/");
  var newdate  = datearray[1] + '/' + datearray[0] + '/' + datearray[2];
  return newdate;
}

//YYYY-MM-DD tp MM\DD\YYYY
var toMmDdYy = function(input) {
    var ptrn = /(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})/;
    if(!input || !input.match(ptrn)) {
        return null;
    }
    return input.replace(ptrn, '$2/$3/$1');
};

//Convert Date based on input to MM\DD\YYYY
function ConverSpedDate(input){
   if( input.lenght > 10 ) return toMmDdYy(input);
    return convertDate(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
convertDate = function( input ){
    if( input.lenght > 10 ) return convertDate( input );
    return toMmDdYy( input );
}
```

Comment: So you mean I will stay on my function and add this one so it will call those functions based on condition? let me try this thnx

Comment: Yes, the only problem with this one is that it wont tell if "input" is a date. Its based on the assumption that "input" has only the format that you gave us. a single space in this input "2017-08-09" ( for example " 2017-08-09" ) is going to be considered the other format.

Comment: true. this code will have an error because it is assuming that the input must be based on the 2 sample.

Comment: How is STD_data[i][4] generated?,
Do you use JS date methods?

Comment: Actually it came from google sheet cell the format in that cell is "MM\DD\YYYY" but when im calling that cell in my script the format changes to timestamp

Comment: Sir as for now TYSM for help. I gave you a credit for that by the way sir I updated my code based on what you given.

Answer (score 0):

You can test each pattern and reformat accordingly. Your reformatting functions appear to be cumbersome and error prone, consider the following:

```js
var startdate = "2017-08-23"
var timestamp = "Thu Aug 31 15:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017"

function reformatTimestamp(s) {

  if (/\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d/.test(s)) {
    return reformatISOtoMDY(s);
    
  } else if (/[a-z]{3} [a-z]{3} \d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \w{3}\+\d\d:\d\d \d{4}/i.test(s)) {
    return reformatCustomToMDY(s);
  }
}

// Reformat YYYY-MM-DD  to MM\DD\YYYY
function reformatISOtoMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b[1] + '\' + b[2] + '\' + b[0];
}

function reformatCustomToMDY(s) {
  var months = '. jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec'.split(' ');
  var b = s.split(/ /);
  return ('0' + months.indexOf(b[1].toLowerCase())).slice(-2) +
    '\' + ('0' + b[2]).slice(-2) + '\' + b[5];
}

console.log(reformatTimestamp(startdate))
console.log(reformatTimestamp(timestamp))
```

The format MM\DD\YYYY is unusual and likely to confuse.

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged this as a GAS question, have you looked at Utilities.formatDate()? Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), but in short it takes 3 parameters: a date object, a time-zone string & a format string. The TZ & format are taken from the [Java SE SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

In your instance, try this:

```
var ts = "Thu Aug 31 15:00:00 GMT+08:00 2017";
var d = new Date(ts);
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT+08:00", "MM/dd/yyyy")); // logs 08/31/2017
```

Note that you will have to set the time-zone in the output yourself. You could extract it from the timestamp via a regex, for example. As the JS Date primitive is milliseconds 1970-01-01T00:00:00 UTC, you can set your output TZ to suit your needs.

I also +1 the recommendations to stick to ISO date & time formats: MM/dd/yyyy absent locale information is just asking for trouble.